# MUMPS doesn't permit to create a file bigger than 2 GB

Tags: aix

We know that MUMPS does not allow to create files bigger than 2 GB.

A Volume Group accepts 16GB, but only with 2 GB for each VG file.

My unix "fsize" parameter it is configured correctly in /etc/security file:

> root:
>
> Fsize_hard = -1
>
> Fsize = -1

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You do not say it is AIX, but /etc/security/(limits) is probably AIX.

Correct the value you want for a "limit" and use the followiung command to change one or more of several values

```
chuser fsize=-1 cpu=-1 data=-1 stack=-1 core=-1 rss=-1 root
```

Consider the following (fsize value is 512-byte blocks)

```
michael@x071:[/home/michael]dc
1024 1024 1024 * * p
1073741824
512 / p
2097152
2 * p
4194304
```

To adjust the classic *ulimit* way, just enter:

```
ulimit -f 4194304
```

To make it permanent (starting with next login) use:

```
chuser -a fsize=4194304 root
```

and you have the max **ulimit** filesize to 2Gbyte (4194304 * 512)

Comment: Michael,
Thanks for your reply, it is always very difficult to find information on this subject.
I actually can create files larger than 2GB on my AIX. That's great
However, my problem is in creating larger files than this in MUMPS. The system does not allow and I can not figure out where to set this parameter.

Comment: It may be "hard-coded" in MUMPS to not support files larger than 2GByte (2^^31 == 2GByte, as 1-bit is used as a sign bit (for forward/reverse seek() calls). As I do not know MUMPS, I would have to suggest the MUMPS documentation and/or VAR support. Someone installed/sold MUPS to the hospital (I assume).